Old animated film with flying creatures born from a pod
I'm trying to find an old animated film. All I can remember is parts of the film. My mom video taped it, so it's probably from the 80s.
Parts I remember is there's an old bearded man at some point smoking a pipe and playing a small guitar in a room where his floor has fish swimming beneath him, a young boy and maybe a girl too.
There's also these small flying creatures that are born from huge pods on the water and I remember they were watching one open up and these creatures flew out, but one was stuck and they had to help it.
Another part I remember is they were in a huge forest with strange fruit growing on the branches that they popped and drank.

This is Maitres du Temps / Time Masters (based on Stefan Vul's "The Orphan of Perdida"), a frequently asked movie here (just put the name in the search box).

This is the scene you remember I guess: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xqVGQ1gEZ80&t=30s.

Is this Les Maîtres du temps (1982) AKA The Masters of Time...?

Les Maîtres du temps (lit. The Masters of Time, a.k.a. Time Masters; Herrscher der Zeit in German; Az idő urai in Hungarian) is a 1982 independent animated science fiction film directed by René Laloux and designed by Mœbius. It is based on the 1958 science fiction novel L'Orphelin de Perdide (The Orphan of Perdide) by Stefan Wul.
The film centres on a boy, Piel, who is stranded on Perdide, a desert planet where giant killer hornets live. He awaits rescue by the space pilot Jaffar, the exiled prince Matton, his sister Belle and Jaffar's old friend Silbad who are trying to reach Perdide and save Piel before it is too late.

There's a scene around 16 minutes into the film where an old bearded man named Silbad is playing a guitar and singing while sitting on a transparent section of floor, through which small fish can be seen swimming beneath him. When he's done playing the guitar, he starts smoking a cigarette and has a conversation with a younger man named Jaffar while still sitting on the transparent floor.
Around 19 minutes in, there's a scene where a boy named Piel is alone in a forest with glowing fruit hanging from the trees. He punctures one of the fruit with his right index finger and drinks some juice from it.
And at around 21 minutes in, there's a scene where Silbad, Jaffar and a woman named Princess Belle are on a balcony by a lake, watching hundreds of small flying creatures emerge from a large pod floating on the water. Two of the creatures get stuck in the pod and Silbad helps to free them.
I found a clip of the first scene on YouTube.




The Masters of Time (1982)

You can also watch the full film at the Internet Archive, albeit with the original French audio and no subtitles.
